Why I have syntax error in comment on Python?
I have a problem I don't understand. I have a syntax error in the first line, which is a comment. I use Spyder to run my code, and the syntax error says "Pyflakes E". It's a really weird problem. Can you help me solve it? Thanks. syntax error in comment
I don't know if the problem comes from Spyder or the Python file.
This is the error I have when I lauch it :
GPT2/gpt-2/models/np_GPT2')
  File "<fstring>", line 1
    (self.name=)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


eg, the actual error shows (self.name=)  as being the actual error, are you by any change running older (<3.8) python ?

My version of python is 3.7.1

Yes, that syntax was introduced in 3.8 so it is infact a Syntax Error..
